# Strange issue with @nestjs/router

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I have a really strange issue with @nestjs router. on some of the calls it `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
   at Object.handle (node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-consumer.js:20:77)
  at LoggingInterceptor.intercept (/dist/utils/logging.interceptor.js:0:0)
    at /node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-consumer.js:22:36
    at InterceptorsConsumer.intercept (/node_modules/@nestjs/core/interceptors/interceptors-consumer.js:24:24)
     at node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:45:60
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
    at async /node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:8:17`

Comment: Please give more details about your setup and when the error occurs, including relevant code snippets is most likely a good idea. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: should have written some recursion that doesnt end or infinite loop.
 share the snippet that is creating the issue

Comment: Do you have a cyclical dependency? i.e: `ModuleA` imports `ModuleB` which imports `ModuleA`?